# Add or update listener for Android calendars

Tags: android, android-calendar

I have gone through this article: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html, but it is only about inserting, deleting and updating events programmatically. However, I couldn't find the listener for manual insertions into the calendar. Can you please help me out with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: then you can Register an [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) with CalendarContract ContentProvider for Listening Changes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But if any update has been occurred, I have to revisit again whole database. I will only not get the id of the table, which has been added or modified or deleted.

Comment: If you are "fast enough" you can directly select the created/modified/deleted items by checking the `DIRTY` and `DELETED` flags (these will typically be reset by the calendar account sync adapter after a short time).